# Move all packages from private npm verdaccio to AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, verdaccio, aws-codeartifact

We are using self hosted http://verdaccio.org as a private npm registry.
Now we decided to move to managed AWS CodeArtifact.
According to what I understand from documentation, AWS CA can only upstream to a public registry (as npmjs.com).
**My question is how can I migrate all my packages including all it's versions from a private npm to AWS CA?**

Thank you in advance,
Oleksii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any generic migration steps from npm repository A to npm repository B should work when the destination is CodeArtifact.

I had success with a utility called 'pkgmigr8or' [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkgmigr8or)

#### Steps to migrate 'chalk-pipe' package from 'npmjs' to 'CodeArtifact':

1. Create a 'packages.txt' file

   ```
    $ cat packages.txt
    chalk-pipe
   ```
2. Login to CodeArtifact:

   ```
    $ aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository npm-store --domain my-domain --domain-owner 123456789012
   ```
3. Make sure you have authentication info for both repository in '~/.npmrc' if the source is also a private repository
4. Install pkgmigr8or

   ```
    # npm install -g pkgmigr8or
   ```
5. Migrate all versions of the package(s):

   ```
    $ pkgmigr8or packages.txt https://my-domain-123456789012.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/npm-store/
   ```

Other similar projects:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/registry-migrate
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-migrate